# Artifactory java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ServletContainerProviderFactory

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jersey, artifactory

I just downloaded the Artifactory zip, unzipped it to a path on C:, set the ARTIFACTORY_HOME env to that path, and ran installService.bat.  All that went well.  The service starts, however the servlet does not deploy.  It appears to be some issue with the bundled Jersey jars (possibly wrong version?).  Has anybody seen this?

Here is the contents of artifactory-stderr.2018-01-17:

```
2018-01-17 16:56:24 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
Jan 17, 2018 4:56:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
Jan 17, 2018 4:56:25 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jan 17, 2018 4:56:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8040"]
Jan 17, 2018 4:56:25 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jan 17, 2018 4:56:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8019"]
Jan 17, 2018 4:56:25 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jan 17, 2018 4:56:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Jan 17, 2018 4:56:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
Jan 17, 2018 4:56:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor [C:\bin\artifactory\tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost\access.xml]
Jan 17, 2018 4:56:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor [C:\bin\artifactory\tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost\artifactory.xml]
Jan 17, 2018 4:56:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processServletContainerInitializers
INFO: Unable to process ServletContainerInitializer for [org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer]. This is most likely due to a class defined in the @HandlesTypes annotation being missing. Enable DEBUG level logging for the full stack trace.
Jan 17, 2018 4:56:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/access]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:630)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1842)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/internal/ServletContainerProviderFactory
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(JerseyServletContainerInitializer.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ServletContainerProviderFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1291)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    ... 13 more

Jan 17, 2018 4:56:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
SEVERE: Error deploying configuration descriptor [C:\bin\artifactory\tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost\access.xml]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/access]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:756)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:630)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1842)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Jan 17, 2018 4:56:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deployment of configuration descriptor [C:\bin\artifactory\tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost\access.xml] has finished in [562] ms
Jan 17, 2018 4:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deployment of configuration descriptor [C:\bin\artifactory\tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost\artifactory.xml] has finished in [2,917] ms
Jan 17, 2018 4:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory [C:\bin\artifactory\tomcat\webapps\ROOT]
Jan 17, 2018 4:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory [C:\bin\artifactory\tomcat\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [32] ms
Jan 17, 2018 4:56:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
Jan 17, 2018 4:56:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8040"]
Jan 17, 2018 4:56:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8019"]
```

Answer (score 2):

I stopped being lazy and figured it out.  Hopefully this helps someone else some day.

I'm not sure why they don't bundle the proper Jersey jars, but whatever.

Download Jersey 2.26 bundle here: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/bundles/jaxrs-ri/2.26/jaxrs-ri-2.26.zip

Download Jersey-Guava here: 
http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/bundles/repackaged/jersey-guava/2.25.1/jersey-guava-2.25.1.jar

Put all those jars into the WEB-INF/lib directories in both of the webapps (artifactory and access).

That's it!